# Calling noConflict() after initialising bootstrap datepicker?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-ui, bootstrap-datepicker

I am trying to use `noConflict()` with bootstrap datepicker to avoid conflict with other jquery plugins.

The bootstrap datepicker docs say:

```
$.fn.datepicker.noConflict provides a way to avoid conflict with other jQuery datepicker plugins:

var datepicker = $.fn.datepicker.noConflict(); // return $.fn.datepicker to previously assigned value
$.fn.bootstrapDP = datepicker;                 // give $().bootstrapDP the bootstrap-datepicker functionality
```

But that didn't work for me, because I was using it with a date range.  The code's author had [this to say](https://github.com/eternicode/bootstrap-datepicker/issues/736):

> Oops! The date range code, itself, calls .datepicker, so you're right,
>   it's broken when coupled with noConflict.
>
> For now, I suggest calling noConflict ***after*** initializing the range
>   picker.

But how do I do that?

I tried this:

```
$('#bookingform .input-daterange').datepicker({
    ...options excluded for brevity...
});
datepicker = $.fn.datepicker.noConflict();
```

And I've tried this:

```
$('#bookingform .input-daterange').datepicker({
    ...options excluded for brevity...
}).noConflict();
```

But I can't seem to get it to work.  Can anybody enlighten me as to what I'm doing wrong (or preferably how I can do it right)?

**Update: For those asking how I initialize a range picker:**

There doesn't appear to be code calling this specifically. Other than the demo code below, it relies on the bootstrap js.  I think the range aspect might be based on the class `.input-daterange` but I'm not sure.

This is the demo code:

```
<div class="input-daterange input-group" id="datepicker">
    <input type="text" class="input-sm form-control" name="start" />
    <span class="input-group-addon">to</span>
    <input type="text" class="input-sm form-control" name="end" />
</div>

$('#sandbox-container .input-daterange').datepicker({
    format: "dd/mm/yyyy"
});
```

Comment: Your code doesn't mention anything about initializing a range picker, only datepicker. where are you initializing the range picker?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure. There is no specific code to call the range aspect of it. I think using the class .input-daterange might do that.

Comment: Why mark this question down?  How can I improve it without an explanation?

Comment: Research how the rangepicker is initialized, and using that information follow the instructions from the author: *"For now, I suggest calling noConflict **after initializing the range picker**."* you haven't done this yet, so you haven't done enough research.

Comment: I presumed "after initializing the rangepicker" referred to the datepicker initialization line: `$('#bookingform .input-daterange').datepicker();`   That is the only related code I have control over.  Other than changing bootstrap source code which is not a good idea for somebody with my skill level. And I didn't think that's what the author meant anyway.

Comment: You are correct, your first attempt is following the owner's directions exactly. Here's how it happens in the src: https://github.com/eternicode/bootstrap-datepicker/blob/master/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js#L1357-L1392 The code doesn't do anything asynchronous, so calling .noConflict on the next line should have done what the owner of the plugin suggested.

Comment: Are you using the latest version of the plugin from github?

Comment: Yes I had the latest version. Had I **uploaded** the latest version?  NO. Idiot.  Now it works as you suggested.  Thank you.   My question was really about the mechanics of how to call noConflict after initialization. You answered that in a comment, if you put it in an answer I'll mark it as such.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first attempt is following the owner's directions exactly. 
Here's where it happens in the src: https://github.com/eternicode/bootstrap-datepicker/blob/master/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js#L1357-L1392

The code doesn't do anything asynchronous, so calling .noConflict on the next line should have done what the owner of the plugin suggested.

Though, looking at the source, it seems that whatever bug caused your original issue is now fixed. .datepicker is not called from within the DateRangePicker class anymore.